# Mapping array of long values from hive to elastic search index

Tags: elasticsearch

I have data in hive in following format

```
user_ids       name       city        owner_ids
[1, 324, 456]  some_name  some_city   [4567, 12345678]
```

I want to be able to search by `user_ids = 324` as filter criteria or `owner_ids` = 12345678 and be able to get back above document as response. (Exact match on ids)

Currently I am using dynamic template for mapping which maps user_ids field to long and I am unable to get any results, what type should I force field mapping of `user_ids` and `owner_ids` to get this response?

Mapping configuration

```
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 3,
    "number_of_replicas": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "strings_as_keywords": {
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Result mapping

```
{
  "user_search" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "doc" : {
        "properties" : {
          "name" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "city" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "ds" : {
            "type" : "date"
          },
          "user_ids" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "owner_ids" : {
            "type" : "long"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Show us your index structure and mapping

Comment: @Gibbs updated with index structure and mapping per your suggestion

Comment: As per my current understanding, you should use this (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html) can you add one same document also?